# Error submitting remote command: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder

Tags: java, glassfish, payara

I'm trying to do `cargo:deployer-redeploy` but keeps on getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.8.1:deployer-redeploy (default-cli) on project backend-server: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.8.1:deployer-redeploy failed: error submitting remote command: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder -> [Help 1]
```

Here's the plugin I am using:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
   <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <container>
         <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
         <type>remote</type>
      </container>
      <configuration>
         <type>runtime</type>
         <properties>
            <cargo.remote.username>${payara.username}</cargo.remote.username>
            <cargo.remote.password>${payara.password}</cargo.remote.password>
            <cargo.glassfish.admin.port>${payara.adminPort}</cargo.glassfish.admin.port>
            <cargo.hostname>${payara.hostname}</cargo.hostname>
         </properties>
      </configuration>
   </configuration>
   <!-- provides JSR88 client API to deploy on Payara Server -->
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.main.deployment</groupId>
         <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Java version. I was getting this error until I found I was accidentally using Java 15. Switching back to Java 8 solved the issue.